# how to use ffmpeg -cookies to download aes encrypted hls stream

Tags: cookies, compilation, ffmpeg, aes, m3u8

i need this cookies, so i can download stream from a m3u8 file,(it has this line

```
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://xxx/myStream.php?wowzasessionid=861683502"
```

so i can get the key right ? ( i have the login credential cookies to that site )

according to this [discussion](http://avcodec.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-trac/2013-October/018661.html), it was there, and i checked the code on [github](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/b73900b8a6c0a23e63e84a5eed0a5b9b3ffe1198/libavformat/http.c), it has the option.

but when i compile it with the default options, there is no cookies option. how do i turn it on ?

```
> ./ffmpeg -buildconf
ffmpeg version N-61050-g2dcaa1b Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Mar  3 2014 14:31:05 with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)
  configuration:
  libavutil      52. 66.100 / 52. 66.100
  libavcodec     55. 52.102 / 55. 52.102
  libavformat    55. 33.100 / 55. 33.100
  libavdevice    55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100
  libavfilter     4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100

  configuration:


> ffmpeg -cookies
/sww/gfx/lib64/python2.6/pytz/__init__.py:32: UserWarning: Module argparse was already imported from /sww/tools/lib64/python2.6/argparse.py, but /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages is being added to sys.path
  from pkg_resources import resource_stream
ffmpeg version 1.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Mar 22 2013 09:58:42 with gcc 4.1.2 (GCC) 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-44)
  configuration: --prefix=/dept/srd/vendor/ffmpeg/bundle.rhel5/ffmpeg1.2.0 --enable-static --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --disable-ffserver --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --extra-cflags=-I/dept/srd/vendor/ffmpeg/extern/rhel5/include --extra-ldflags=-L/dept/srd/vendor/ffmpeg/extern/rhel5/lib --enable-x11grab --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-fontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-swscale --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libfaac
  libavutil      52. 18.100 / 52. 18.100
  libavcodec     54. 92.100 / 54. 92.100
  libavformat    54. 63.104 / 54. 63.104
  libavdevice    54.  3.103 / 54.  3.103
  libavfilter     3. 42.103 /  3. 42.103
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
Unrecognized option 'cookies'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

Comment: me too! :((((((

Comment: we have to find a workaround to intercept every single request made by ffmpeg. And I dont know how to do it